# WPF: How to handle errors with a BackgroundWorker

Tags: wpf, multithreading, exception, error-handling, backgroundworker

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to windows client programming. I have a background worker that has a DoWork event and a RunCompleted event wired up. If an exception gets thrown in DoWork, I want to make changes to my UI, however, I cant because it is in a different thread. I can communicate the error to RunCompleted, but that doesn't help me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. Basically, you want code like this:

```
void UpdateState(WhatEverType someObject)
{
    if (! Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(()=>UpdateState(someObject));
    }
    else
    {
        //make the UI changes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good answer, I like the way it calls itself through the dispatcher. Thank you :)