# WPF and backgroundworker problem

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my program there is a BackgroundWorker class that preloads the images to BitmapImage object. I need to pass that preloaded image to the main application(WPF), where it will be copied to another BitmapImage object. This seems to be working, however, when i try

```
imgViewer.Source = imgNext;  //imgNext is a main app copy of the preloaded image
```

an error occurs meaning that that object(imgNext) is owned by another thread and it cannot be used.

Any ideas how to get rid of it and get the code working?

Thanks everybody for answering!

In fact, I managed to solve this problem by creating a static `BitmapImage` inside `App` class.
Before using it, I do

```
 App.iNext = null;
```

Then I load the actual image and freeze it, so this static property can be accessed from everywhere. When the cycle repeats many times, assigning null prevents 'object is frozen' errors.

And of course, there was a lot of work with managing single BGW instance, queuing tasks etc.

*(Currently I'm using ImagesContainer class defined also in my program that has two BitmapImage properties. I use it to receive preloaded images from backgroundworker. )*

*imgNext is a public variable defined in MainWindow. (main thread)*

```
 void bwImgLoader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            backgrLoadNextPrevList list =  e.Argument as backgrLoadNextPrevList;
            ImagesContainer result = new ImagesContainer();
            if (list.HasNextPath) result.imgPrev = PrepareImage(list.NextPath);
            if (list.HasPrevPath) result.imgNext = PrepareImage(list.PrevPath);
            e.Result = result;
        }
void bwImgLoader_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImagesContainer result  = e.Result as ImagesContainer;
            if (result.imgNext != null)
            {
                setNextDelegate s = new setNextDelegate(setNext);
                object[] t = { result.imgNext };
                imgNext.Dispatcher.Invoke(s, t);
            }
            // do not take into account this line, just ignore it. 
            //if (result.imgPrev != null) imgPrev = result.imgPrev;
        }
        public void setNext(BitmapImage b)
        {
            imgNext = b;
        }
        public delegate void setNextDelegate(BitmapImage b);
```

Freezing the bitmapimage helps only on the first background load(see the comment under the answer below). When I call BackgroundWorker second time, an errors occures that the object is frozen and cannot be modified. Is there a way to un-freeze it?

Or, is there any way to copy data from one thread to another without copying an attribution to thread?

---

---

**UPDATED**

Thanks everybody for answering!

In fact, I managed to solve this problem by creating a static `BitmapImage` inside `App` class.
Before using it, I do

```
 App.iNext = null;
```

Then I load the actual image and freeze it, so this static property can be accessed from everywhere. When the cycle repeats many times, assigning null prevents errors.

And of course, there was a lot of work with managing single BGW instance, queuing tasks etc.

But these efforts were worth the result - I got +125% in performance!!! Thank everyone!

Comment: You have an empty `catch { }` block in there.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532740/wpf-how-to-handle-errors-with-a-backgroundworker

Comment: @ Will Hughes : that doesn't help. I need to assing a source for ui element that is owned by another thread

Comment: What's happening in PrepareImage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BitmapImage` is `Freezable` so you can `Freeze()` it after loading it. This will permit access from any thread.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I need to change this image. I do background loading a number of times. Despite I create a new instance in bwImgLoader_DoWork, an error says that the image is frozen when I do the second background load. How can I remove the frozen state (or re-initialize the object)?

Comment: +1 For freeze. Love the way you can turn on immutability with this - interesting design pattern. Totally [breakdance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze_\(breakdance_move\)) too :)

Comment: @semyon You'll have to alter your design so that you create a new BitmapImage after you frozen and used one.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to create all UI objects on the same thread. This includes any classes descending from `DispatcherObject`, such as `BitmapImage`.

On the UI thread - before creating the BGW - capture the result of `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. You can stick it in a private member of your class. e.g.:

```
private TaskScheduler ui;
public void InitiateBGW()
{
  this.ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  this.bwImgLoader.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

On the BGW, whenever you need to access `BitmapImage` functionality (creating them or modifying them), queue it to the `TaskScheduler` like this:

```
private BitmapImage PrepareImage(string path)
{
  // This code runs in a BGW.

  // Load underlying bitmap (non-UI)...
  var bitmap = ..;
  // Prepare the bitmap (non-UI)...

  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    var ret = new BitmapImage();
    // Load "bitmap" into "ret"
    return ret;
  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, this.ui);
}
```